# Read file names from directory in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to write a script that reads all the file names from a directory and then depending on the file name, for example if it contains R1 or R2, it will concatenates all the file names that contain, for example R1 in the name.

Can anyone give me some tip how to do this?

The only thing I was able to do is:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="path to the files"

for f in $FILES
do
  cat $f
done
```

and this only shows me that the variable FILE is a directory not the files it has.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make the smallest change that fixes the problem:

```
dir="path to the files"
for f in "$dir"/*; do
  cat "$f"
done
```

To accomplish what you describe as your desired end goal:

```
shopt -s nullglob
dir="path to the files"
substrings=( R1 R2 )
for substring in "${substrings[@]}"; do
  cat /dev/null "$dir"/*"$substring"* >"${substring}.out"
done
```

Note that `cat` can take multiple files in one invocation -- in fact, if you aren't doing that, you usually don't need to use cat at all.

Comment: This just returns $dir/* for me

Comment: @LelandReardon It will do that if your directory is empty (or otherwise the glob expression returns no results). To turn that off and return an empty list on that case, run `shopt -s nullglob`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple hack:

> ls -al *R1* | awk '{print $9}' >outputfilenameR1
>
> ls -al *R2* | awk '{print $9}' >outputfilenameR2

Comment: If your filenames contain spaces, `print $9` will only pick out the first part. And see the other caveats in [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation that

```
for f in $FILES
```

will loop over all the file names which are stored in the directory defined by the variable FILES was disappointed by the fact that you had observed that the value of FILES was the only item processed in the for loop.

In order to create a list of files out of the value pointing to a directory it is necessary to provide a pattern for file names which if applied to the file system will give a list of found directory and file names upon evaluation of the pattern by using $FILES.

This can be done by appending of /* to the directory pattern string stored in the variable FILES which is then used to be evaluated to a list of file names using the $-character as directive for the shell to evaluate the value stored in FILES and replace $FILES with a list of found files. The pure * after /* guarantees that all entries in the directory are returned, so the list will contain not only files but also sub-directories if there are any.

In other words if you change the assignment to:

```
FILES="path to the files/*"
```

the script will then behave like you have expected it.