# Checking if substring is in filename in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a script that identifies the names of files in a directory and then checks to see if a string is a substring of the name. I'm doing this in bash and cannot use the `grep` command. Any thoughts?

I have the following code to check if a user submission matches a file name or a string in the name.

```
read -p name 

for file in sample/*; do
    echo $(basename "$file")
    if [[$(basename "$file") ~= $name]];
    then echo "invalid"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881157/read-file-names-from-directory-in-bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file names from directory in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881157/read-file-names-from-directory-in-bash)

Comment: Tangentially see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

You can just interpolate the user input into the wildcard.

```
printf '%s\n' sample/*"$name"*
```

If you want to loop over the matches, try

```
for file in sample/*"$name"*; do
    # cope with nullglob
    test -e "$file" || break
    : do things with "$file"
done
```

If you just need to check that the name isn't a substring of an existing file's name:

```
valid=true
for file in sample/*"$name"*; do       
    test -e "$file" && valid=false
done
echo "$name is valid? $valid"
```

The shell by default does not expand a wildcard which doesn't match any files; so in this case, your loop will run once, but the loop variable will not match any existing file.  You might also want to look at the `nullglob` option in Bash to make it loop zero times in this case.